# Graphing an integrated max equation

Tags: integration, graphing-functions

Evaluate the integral and sketch the region in $x-y$ plane,

> $$\int^1_0\int^1_0 x\ \operatorname{max}(x^2,y)\ \mathrm{d}y\ \mathrm{d}x.$$

I have already integrated the equation with when $x^2 > y$ and when $y > x$. Both also have the result of $\frac14$. I just wanna know how do I graph this to show which region is when $x^2$ is larger than $y$ and which region is when $y$ is larger than $x^2$?

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFRGy.png)

Comment: Graph $y=x^2$: what's on one side of it is where $y>x^2$, and the other side is $y<x^2$.

Comment: I graphed that on desmos and apparently they have a shared region. Can you explain what is that shared region?

Answer (score 1):

After following @lisyarus advice I have concluded this graph
[Attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGEh3.png)